# average value of inputs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in intro programming class and I just started learning the loops. My question asks about the average value of the inputs and it supposed to be done with while-loops. When the user inputs end instead of a number, that signifies the end of the loop and calculates the average value. The program should print the average value and return it. Also, if the user does not input any number and directly inputs end, the program should print "No numbers were entered". I tried creating the loop, but I do not know what I am missing for my loop to be running. 
Also, I am not allowed to use any inbuilt functions like sum, ave, etc.

Here is the code I've written so far

```
def avgOfTheSum(): 
    total = 0 
    avg = 0 
    count = 0 
    while True: 
        number = input("Enter next number:") 
        if number != 'end': 
            num = float(number) 
            total = total + num 
            count = count + 1 
            average = total/count 
        else: 
            print("The Average is:",average) 
            break 
    return average
```

Comment: Please share your code so far

Comment: I'm guessing you're also not allowed to ask for other people to do your homework for you, like you're asking here. We do not write code for people. Read [this](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?newreg=1216e0ad88d74ebbab12ba8299cc7e3c).

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: I started writing my code, but I got stuck and this was the only place I could think for help. I am sorry I was just looking for guidance. Here is my code so far.
def avgOfTheSum():
    total = 0
    avg = 0
    count = 0
    while True:
        number = input("Enter next number:")
        if number != 'end':
            num = float(number)
            total = total + num
            count = count + 1
            average = total/count
        
        else:
            print("The Average is:",average)
            break
        return average

Comment: can you move your code to the question section?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Done

Comment: Asking on SO about problems you encounter while writing homework is perfectly fine, but you should do it in a different manner. You ask *"This is my task. This is what I did. Finish it for me."* Instead of that, you should determine which part does not work, try to understand why it does not work (don't forget to use google) and if you are still stuck, ask something like *"I expected this code to do X, but it does Y instead. Why?"*

Answer (score 2):

a few tips from my not-so-experienced point of view :

when you increment a variable, eg. 'total = total + num', you can do so with a more compact way : use 'total += num' which does exactly the same thing and lightens your code. Some people find it ugly though, so use it if you will.

You first declared a variable named 'avg' but you then later use 'average', which leads to an error when trying to print 'average' which was not defined because the first 'if' statement was bypassed. 
You should use one naming for the average. Either 'avg' or 'average' is okay but remember your code must be easy to understand so try not to squeeze things too much, especially if someone is reviewing it when you are finished.
Use one name and stick to it. That way you don't have an error when the user inputs something that isnt handled by your code.

You could add safe nets to ensure the user passes a number but the most simple ways need to use python built-ins.

You could add something like (not python do not write it like so)
if count = 0 
then print 'no numbers entered'
then either :
break if you want to quit the application
or pass if you want to force the user to enter a number (enforcing a new loop)

Hope it helped you a little bit !